# Eclipse running previous program

Tags: eclipse

It is a new problem. I copy paste a program and try to run it in eclipse. But the eclipse keeps running an older program. I have no idea what is going on. ( I saved the program as someone on the internet suggested) In the run button, there are only old programs. So I goes into the run configuration option and double clicked the java application option and somehow the one I am working on right now appeared. And I am able to compile and run the current one. So technically I solved the problem, but I would like an explanation, what was going on?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to run, but have you done the things needed to make it a runnable Java class in general?

Comment: What do you mean? It is a runnable java class. I was trying to run nonrecursive fibonacci but it keeps gave me results from srudebtlist. The option of nonrecursivefibonacci does not appear until i double clicked java application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What is going on here is how Eclipse decides what to Run when you press the `Run` button. My suspicion is you have settings which are causing it to launch the last launched item, rather than something new that does not have a launch configuration. If you hover over the `Run` icon, it will show the name of the launch configuration that Eclipse will launch.

For a new program, you want to do a `Run As` -> `Java Application` (From `Run` menu).

To configure the default launching behaviour, see `Preferences` -> `Run/Debug` -> `Launching`, and then set the options you want in the `Launch Operation` group.

[image: launching preference page]

Answer (score 0):

It just copies path of the server from old project.
It has the **TWO solutions** :

**1)** you can simply click on your Tomcat->Modules (Web Modules)-> Edit

[image]

And simply change the path with you project name or just put "/".

[image]

**OR**

**2)** You can right click on your project -> Properties-> Web Prjoect Settings

edit Context root, just simply put "/"

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I run into the same problem (I am new in java). I solved the problem by * I ensure did not use the defaul package . Step 1. Create java application. Step 2. Create package (stay away from default package). Step3. Create a class that will have my getters and setters (example:

```
package revature;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName("vijaiy");;
        //getting value of the member
        System.out.println(s.getName());

    }

}
```

Step 4. Create the main class to run the program
Example:

```
package revature;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName("vijaiy");;
        //getting value of the member
        System.out.println(s.getName());

    }

}
```

My problem was that I did not set up my brain to think 'java', I was thinking on 'javascript'.

Answer (score -3):

Exit out of eclipse, then open Eclipse in a new Workspace and create a new Project. This is a quick solution if you are willing to have multiple workspaces.