# My eclipse neon running the exact previous snapshot of Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I am using eclipse neon 4.6.3 in ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly today I have noticed that it is compiling and running the immediate previous snapshot of the code.

For example, I had a code like this:

```
System.out.println("1");
```

After running this if I change it like this:

```
System.out.println("2");
```

It will print: 1

That means it is running the previous runned snapshot of the code. As a result I have to run every program twice to observe the output.

I have tried to open new project, delete previous  projects, restart eclipse etc. Nothing worked. However, when I run python scripts in eclipse, that works fine.

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks in advance

Edit: When I go to Window > Preferences > Launch it shows this:

[image]

May be this will be helpful to find out the problem.

Comment: Eclipse (Project-->Build Automatically) is it checked? if yes than when you save it, It will automatic save and compile and should change the output

Comment: Yes it is checked. IS not there any auto saving options in eclipse?

Comment: Did you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337496/eclipse-running-previous-program

Comment: look into `preferences-Run/Debug->Launching`, the first two properties should **not** have selected *never*.

Comment: Yes. I have seen it.

Probably you are saying Window> Preferences>Launch

I have added the screen-shot of it. Nothing happed after changing this.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.

Go to Window > Preferences > Launching

Check the General option: Build (if required) before launching

Then it will be ok.

[image: After fixing the issue]

Thank you all for trying to help me.