# Eclipse seems to be running a newer and older version of my Java JDA Discord bot at the same time? Why and how is this happening?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The JDA Discord bot is created as so using Maven and Eclipse. Not all of the code is displayed here.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{   
    JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(Ref.token).buildBlocking();
    jda.addEventListener(new App());
}
```

The Method handling the event is below.

The Discord bot is running a previous version of my method for some reason and is printing "Has started a new game of Poker!" by itself. It is also printing the code as it currently shown in Eclipse?

```
public void gameSetup(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {
    User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
    Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();

    if(objMsg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(">gameSetup")) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();//start time
        objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();//set the message channel for the game
        objMsgCh.sendMessage(objUser.getAsMention()+"Has started a new game of Poker! Type '>joinGame' to join").queue();
        objMsgCh.sendMessage(objUser.getAsMention()+"NEW").queue();
    }
}
```

[Picture of Discord chat Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4toqx.png)

How can I stop Eclipse from running an Older and Newer edit of my code simultaneously? If that is the problem.

Comment: This will only happen if both methods are being called. Use the search function and find where `Has started a new game of Poker!` is being used in your code because you may have put it somewhere else and forgot to remove it. If it does not exist anywhere else in your code, then you must have included and referenced your older version somehow, so check your imports, references and libraries. Other than that, we can not really help without seeing more of the relevant code.

Comment: @sorifiend thanks for the response! After doing some searching I discovered that Eclipse was in fact running two separate instances of my application. For some reason my preferences were set to make my run button do this.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was actually similar to this.

[Eclipse running previous program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337496/eclipse-running-previous-program)

It appears my Preferences were set to make my Run button launch a previous AND current version of my code. I fixed this by going in to the Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching then selecting "Launch the associated project" rather than "Launch the previously launched application"